# Why does argparse order matter with an optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I have some code to parse some arguments in a file called "blah.py":

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('opt', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('--bool', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('value')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I call this file like so:

```
blah.py a b --bool
```

It works correctly (opt='a', value='b', bool=True).

However, if I call this in a different order:

```
blah.py a --bool b
```

I would expect the same result, but the argparse module is printing an `error: unrecognized arguments: b` message.  Is this a bug with the argparse module?  Why does it work this way, and what can I do to avoid running into issues like these, as I define the CLI for my script?

As my interface is much more complex than the example (having subcommands and many more arguments), I have varying ways to call the interface which requires some arguments to be optional for some calls, but mandatory for others.  I plan to manually verify these cases, and on an error call parser.print_usage and exit.

Comment: Historical aside: POSIX rules for command-line parsing specify that options *always* come before positional arguments (see Guideline 9 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), and thus that any value after a non-option (and non-option-argument) can be considered positional (an "operand" rather than an "option" or "option-argument"). Teaching users that they can mix options and positional arguments willy-nilly is largely the fault of the GNU project... but it's something optparse and argparse have perpetuated, so here we are. :-/

Comment: And just FYI, if you run an argparse command without any args or with `-h` you will see a usage example as follows: `blah.py [-h] [--bool] [opt] value` thus showing you where it expects the options and arguments.

Comment: Normally argparse allows arguments in any order.  But when one of positionals is `?`, mixing a flagged option in the middle causes problems.  So either keep the positionals together (at end or beginning), or use the new `intermixed` parser.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the history, if I need to change the suggested call, I supposed I'd best follow convention. :)

Comment: I'm using 3.6, but have downloaded the `argparse` from the 3.7 for testing.  It's a self contained file so can used in earlier distributions.

Comment: Positionals with `?` (or * or +) can be convenient, but do complicate parsing.  Changing them to flagged arguments can remove some parsing ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the "intermixed" options of argparser

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing

Otherwise, positional arguments always come before optional arguments.

Comment: Good to know there's something coming in python 3.7, although I unfortunately can't upgrade at this point in time.  Thanks!

Comment: Normally positionals can occur in any order relative to flagged ones.  `usage` shows them after.  It's this case of a `?` argument that has problems.